# Instance geometry Frustum culling

Tags: three.js

I am facing a issue in frustum culling.
We know in Three.js frustum culling is default, if needed we can set

> mesh.frustumCulled =false;

my issue is how to implement frustum culling in instance geometry,
If i enable

> mesh.frustumCulled = true

all the instance data culled from scene while the original instance culled from frustum,
because my original geometry is in one position, instance will be place by the matrix(position,rotation,scale).
I used InstanceBufferGeometry and InterleavedBufferAttribute as described in three.js example
[webgl_interactive_instances_gpu](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=webgl_interactive_instances_gpu#webgl_interactive_instances_gpu)

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instancing occurs on the gpu; frustum culling on the cpu.

If you are using instancing, you can either disable frustum culling for your mesh

```
mesh.frustumCulled = false;
```

or you can manually specify the bounding sphere

```
mesh.geometry.boundingSphere = new THREE.Sphere( new THREE.Vector3(), radius );
```

If you need to update the bound sphere,

```
mesh.geometry.boundingSphere.center.set( x, y, z );
mesh.geometry.boundingSphere.radius = radius;
```

three.js r.93

Comment: thanks @WestLangley, that's right, as you said we can manually set the bounding sphere, by doing this if all instance data out from frustum it will be clipped, but my need is to clip one instance data if it out from frustum

Comment: That is not possible with instancing. The only way to limit the number of instances rendered is to set `mesh.geometry.maxInstancedCount = numInstances`.

Comment: Thanks @westLankley. Right now Iam using maxInstanceCount only, is there any possiblity to show 5 out of 10 instance in [1,2,3...10] i need to show [1,5,6,8,9] likewise.

Comment: Yes, but that is a question unrelated to frustum culling: set the instance position away from the camera, or add a instance visibility attribute and toggle it.

Comment: Thanks @WestLangley, well said, I did setting a  flag attrib to toggle the visibility, and use in fragment shader to discard.