# Threejs update single material on glb with multiple objects

Tags: three.js, aframe

I have a .glb model which has multiple objects and materials.  I'm updating the children that have a certain material at runtime, but as there are nearly 1,000 children with this material it's choking a little.  I'm looking for a more elegant solution if it exists.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('apply-texture', {
    schema: {
        texture: { type: 'string' }
    },
    init: function() {
        var data = this.data;
        var el = this.el;
        var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
        var alphamap = loader.load("./images/PETAL-DATA.jpg");

        el.object3D.traverse(function(child) {
if (child.isMesh && child.material.name == "Material_to_update") {

                var texture = loader.load(data.texture,
                    function ( texture ) {
                        child.material.map = texture;
                        child.material.alphaMap = alphamap;
                        child.material.map.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
                        child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                        child.material.color.set("#FFFFFF");
                        child.material.alphaTest = 0.5;
                        child.material.opacity = 0.8;
                        child.material.needsUpdate = true;

                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                        console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                        console.log( 'An error happened' );
                    }
                );
                
            }
```

As all the child objects are using the same material I'm hoping there's a way of just updating the material itself rather than the 1,000 children.

Comment: Why are you loading the texture on each loop????? You only need the texture to load once!

Comment: good point @jscastro I've amended that, but still have the issue of traversing a model with alot of children

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating 1000 image loaders, use a system which will provide the loaded texture to each component:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // register system
  AFRAME.registerSystem("image-provider", {
    init: function() {
      // load some external image
      this.image = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
        "https://i.imgur.com/wjobVTN.jpg"
      );
    },
    getImage() {
      // the components will grab the image via this function
      return this.image;
    }
  });
  
  // register the component
  AFRAME.registerComponent("image-provider", {
    init: function() {
      // grab the system reference
      const system = this.system;
      // wait until the model is loaded
      this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", e => {
        // grab the mesh
        const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
        // apply the texture from the system
        mesh.traverse(node => {
          if (node.material) {
            node.material.map = system.getImage();
            node.material.needsUpdate = true;
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
</script>

<body>
  <div style="z-index: 99999; position: fixed; top: 2.5%">
    <p>
      Model by <a href="https://poly.google.com/view/8kcvUY9eTf">Kelli Ray</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <a-scene background="color: #FAFAFA">
    <a-assets>
      <a-asset-item id="model" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/994b27e1-a801-47b8-9b52-9547b8f25fc1%2Fgoogle%20poly.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      <a-mixin id="fish" gltf-model="#model" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001" image-provider></a-mixin>
    </a-assets>
    <a-text position="-1.5 2 -3" color="black" value="original"></a-text>
    <a-entity gltf-model="#model" position="-1 1 -3" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"></a-entity>
    <a-entity position="0 1 -3" mixin="fish"></a-entity>
    <a-entity position="1 1 -3" mixin="fish"></a-entity>
    <a-entity position="2 1 -3" mixin="fish"></a-entity>
    <a-entity position="3 1 -3" mixin="fish"></a-entity>
  </a-scene>
```

---

If You have multiple identical objects, you should look into [Instanced Meshes](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/InstancedMesh) - which allow you to place multiple objects while creating only one draw call. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729937/how-to-use-three-instancedmesh-in-aframe) SO thread. You can check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/models/instanced.html) ([source](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/aframe/models/instanced.html))

Comment: never used registerSystem before - will look into that - I'm passing the image to the component at runtime I guess that syntax is still the same and is handled by the schema

Could 1 system return more than 1 image to use ie diffuse & alpha maps or will I have to write another system for each?

Comment: I guess what I'm trying to do is avoid having to traverse the model and just make an update to 1 material in the model, which in turn updates all objects that have that material applied

Comment: @heroicsatsuma how about we reverse the roles, and the system will apply the textures / normals / whatever you want to the entity - which will be provided by a component https://jsfiddle.net/dvpyjn8g/

Answer (score 0):

"I guess what I'm trying to do is avoid having to traverse the model and just make an update to 1 material in the model, which in turn updates all objects that have that material applied"

If multiple mesh are actually sharing the same exact material (meaning they have the same uuid), if you update a property of the material then it'll update on all mesh using that material. I'm guessing they're not all sharing the same material though.

From what you've said, I think you just need to make your updates to the first mesh's material, create a variable referencing that material, then traverse your model and apply that material to every applicable mesh. For memory sake, it would also be good to `.dispose()` the materials that your replacing.