# Is there an instancing component available for A-Frame to optimize my scene with many repeated objects?

Tags: aframe

I have an A-Frame scene with many copies of the same entity (gltf model). Is there a way to reduce draw calls by using instancing from three.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few A-Frame components that support some level of instancing:

- https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/instanced-mesh - most recent
- https://github.com/EX3D/aframe-InstancedMesh - basic support
- https://github.com/takahirox/aframe-instancing - experimental, out of date
- https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/master/aframe/models/instanced.html - code sample from [How to use Three.InstancedMesh in Aframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729937/how-to-use-three-instancedmesh-in-aframe)